# Bintray API: Upload package avatar

Tags: bintray

I would like to update my package avatar using directly Bintray API. Is there some way?

The only way that I have to updade is using the web interface:

[image: bintray]

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [Bintray REST API](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_packages), it looks like it is currently not supported.

Comment: Yes, I read the API docs and I didn't find any info about. Thanks for checking this.